# How to find the sum $\cos(2x)+\cos(4x)+\cos(6x)+\cos(8x)+\ldots+\cos(2016x)$?

Tags: trigonometry, trigonometric-series

Find the sum $$M= \cos(2x)+\cos(4x)+\cos(6x)+\cos(8x)+\ldots+\cos(2016x)$$

Answer (score 2):

Invoke the geometric series theorem on this.

$$\sum_{k=1}^{1008} \cos(2kx) = \Re\left(\sum_{k=1}^{1008} e^{2ikx}\right).$$

Comment: That's how I would have done it.  +1

Comment: It won't allow me to plug this into my calculator, would you be able to provide me with more steps? Or detailed explanation?